# linq not supported filter by the first element of a list?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

For business logic, the number of elements of a navigation propoerty that is a collection is one element, so I try to use this linq query to folter data:

```
myQuery = myQyuery.Where(c => c.MyEntity.ElementAt(0).MyBoolProperty == true);
```

But I get an exception that says more or less that linq is not compatible with `ElementAt()`, or that it is not recognize the function.

How could I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
myQuery= myQyuery.Where(c=>c.MyEntity.FirstOrDefault().MyBoolProperty== true);
```

Comment: Side note - you don't need to compare boolean value with `true`